# Web Service - Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have added a Web Service to an existing asp.net intranet application.  The purpose is to expose functionality to other intranet applications on the same domain.

The intranet application uses Windows authentication.  How can I setup the web service to use Windows authentication?

Comment: Another way to look at it-if you are using static IPs, keep a table of what user is on which IP.

Comment: It is interesting that such a question remains. If you already resolved it on your own, post the answer and accept it, or simply delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Client.localhost.Service1 service = new Client.localhost.Service1();
   service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pass", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the web service to use Windows Authentication is easy. You just change the authentication mode in IIS!

Communicating with that service is another matter. First of all, you need to set up the service reference properly in the consuming application's web config. The security section below is the most critical part in getting this to work.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://yourservice.com/Service.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap"
    contract="ServiceClient.IServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
</client>
```

Then, you need to set the **Windows** credentials of the client object before you begin using it.

```
var credentials = ServiceSoapClient.ClientCredentials;
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "domain";
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "user";
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "pwd";
credentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
```

Comment: would you consider it bad practice to expose a very small part of an ASP.NET application with a web service? It is an internal application that will link to another internal application.

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice to create a small web service to allow two applications to communicate, but I welcome any other opinions.

Comment: Thanks.  You have quoted code from the web.config in your answer.  Is this code generated automatically if you create a service reference for the web service?

Comment: Usually, the code in the web config is at least partly configured. However, in my experience it doesn't always get set up quite right for Windows Auth. That's why I posted it. You may need to correct the security section.